What are you making it mean about you? VS What do you think it means about you?
An autistic person is answering the questions. One of the questions is:

If someone doesn't understand you, what are you making it mean about you? Big Think - Diagnosis (see:2:07-2:12)

The second part "....make it mean..." sounds somewhat difficult for me at the first glance. I think it means the same as ".... what do you think it means about you?". But I am not a 100% sure. So I want to verify.
Does "....what are making it mean about you?" mean the same as "..... what do you think it means about you?"

It's an odd and unidiomatic expression. Your guess is as good as a native speaker's!

It sounds like cant.

The wording is intended to convey the idea that a thing's meaning is very much a function of the person doing the interpreting. Thus, if a man says to his wife, "You look lovely" but she has a very poor self-image, then she may assume that it would be impossible for anyone to find her attractive, and therefore decide that he is trolling her and conclude that his true intention is to insult her.
In that case, although the husband may have meant his remark as a sincere compliment, based on her particular experiences, personality, and filters, she is "making it mean" something quite different.
So I'd say that, no, it doesn't mean quite the same thing as What do you think it means about you? That question invites someone to (essentially) make their best estimate of what "it (objectively) means." But What are you making it mean about you? is pointing out that--whether consciously or not--the person is creating an interpretation (and perhaps merely assuming that that interpretation is an accurate reflection of "the actual meaning").

It's not a common idiomatic pattern, so don't worry about copying it. But the meaning is clear enough, especially given the response: You're right in guessing that "what do you make it mean" basically means "what do you think it means." It's similar to the idiom "What do you make of it." There's a lot of usage of "make" along with talking about meaning or understanding in some advanced, academic fields of psychology or philosophy, talking about "meaning-making" and so on. But I suspect that this question was just hastily written.
